# Rails NameError (uninitialized constant Registration): 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am currently using Cancan and my users basically have different 'roles'.
I only want people to be able to register 'consumer' user accounts and for business accounts admins will be doing that.

So now, I have this in my ability.rb

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new  
    ... 
    # You can only create accounts that are consumers
    can :create, User do |user|
      user.role? :consumer 
    end
```

and in my controller/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

and config/routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
    :registrations => "users/registrations"
  }
```

Now when I visit the registration page, I am seeing "uninitialized constant Registration" with NO stack trace whatsoever. Any ideas?

Comment: If you remove the lines in `ability.rb` does the problem go away?

Answer (score 0):

My code example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  authorize_resource
  check_authorization
end

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_authorize_resource
  skip_authorization_check
end
```

For `load_and_authorize_resource` you will need `skip_load_and_authorize_resource`. And all this code is applicable for custom `devise`'s controller. Just create one.

Comment: Is it safe to skip authorization check like this?

Comment: Yes, because you don't have a way to authorize by session token while session is not created.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the routes, please follow the following steps

```
 1. $ rake routes, you will see the list of routes 

 2. In your config/routes.rb write the route you need, In my case the route to create a new user was,     
   devise_for :users,  :controllers => { :new_user_registration => "users/registrations#new" }
 3. restart rails server
```